# Where to ask questions pertaining to microfabrication?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Specifically, which site is appropriate for asking more general questions that are likely to arise in a cleanroom setting? On which site would these questions receive the most views/answers from knowledgeable users?

Since tags are a product of what users want to ask, and they are limited by what users are allowed to ask, then there absence has merit in my eyes.
**Physics** and **Engineering** lack "cleanroom" relevant tags so they are probably not the answer.

For those who think the solution is to just create new tags, well for one, I am far from 1500 rep & will probably never make it there, but more importantly: microfabrication has remained a very teaming industry for a very long time now, most fabrication methods/processes have steep learning curves and change on the regular, and online info is scarce/unavailable/conflicting or hard to find (i.e., a needle in a haystack of academic papers). There should be an abundance of people looking for answers but since this current of people doesn't funnel into the **Physics** and **Engineering** sites, there must be a good reason.

**Electronics** is the only site that has some relevant tags but [questions must somehow be related to electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (go figure). Of course, microfabrication designs that feature electrical characteristics are only a cog in the large field of microfabrication.

Where can I ask general questions such as "Using the Wulff-Jaccodine method, what would the profile of this Si side wall look like after etching with..."?

Comment: Are you looking for microfabrication on a specific field? You already stated it's not electronic related, but perhaps if you tell us the field of the question you want to ask will have more clues on where would be ideal to do so...

Comment: Like for microfab questions related to electronics you could ask them on Electronics but what I am asking for is a place to ask general questions about microfab, NOT specific to any sub-fields of microfab.

Comment: @DarkCygnus I gave an example at the end (:

Comment: So you don't actually have a question in mind? And are just asking about possible hypothetical questions you *may* have eventually?... I'm saying this because there would be a difference in knowing the industry your microfab relates to, so we can help you find an *existing* site... otherwise if it is about microfabs in general then a specific site could be needed

Comment: I have many questions actually, but most of them are general like the one I already provided. It would be cool if  there was just 1 all inclusive site where you could ask any general question regarding microfab. I am entering the MEMS field but right now I am just trying to familiarize myself with general cleanroom processes/equipment/tools etc.